# How do I uninstall Python 2 from Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python3

Oddly didn't find any answers, and since I've never uninstalled anything from Linux, I don't know where to start. I need Python3, and only have SSH access to the machine where I'm doing this un/install.

I'd like to uninstall Python2 and all packages, and install Python3. Is there any simple command to run in order to do the first part of uninstalling Python2?

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall Python2? You can have both of them on your system.

Comment: Apt and apt-get are command line tools for manipulating software packages. Most Linux commands line tools accept `--help` parameter to display what they can do.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to uninstall Python 2 in order to install Python 3.  `apt-get install python3` will install it in parallel.  Also, in Ubuntu, the minimal subset of Python provided by `python-minimal` is [an essential package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python), so uninstalling it could have catastrophic consequences.

Comment: Depending on the release.  Older distributions do rely on Python 2.  Though I don't believe any currently-supported LTS releases do, some folks may still be running post-EOL versions.

Comment: Yeah I realize that 2 and 3 can be installed together but I've had issues previously where they were both installed and causing confusion for development. Granted this was for a Pyspark application, but I'd like to avoid that as much as possible

Comment: My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (still supported) has 56 python2 executables in /usr/bin (and 77 python3 ones).

Comment: The confusion can be mitigated by always using the `python2` and `python3` executables, rather than relying on the pointing of `python` to the flavor you hope to be using.

Comment: If you do need to keep both, it is easy enough to make sure that python3 is found whenever a script runs python, e.g.: